# Performance issue with moving html with javascript on mobile device?

Tags: javascript, mobile

What is the likely performance impact for mobile devices if I use javascript to move some html from the bottom to the top of the page?

I want to create a menu like the [boston globe](http://bostonglobe.com/) where on mobile devices you just have a menu button, and clicking it makes the menu appear.

The issue is that my menu is at the bottom of my page. So I could absolutely position it at the top, hide it, and then reveal it when you click the button. The issue is that it will cover the content underneath it. I cant change the source order of my html, so the only solution i can think of is the use JavaScript to move the entire menu. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most mobile devices that you'd probably be looking to target would have quite decent JS engines.  In my experience the JS performance on mobile devices is quite impressively fast so I wouldn't worry about the performance impact of moving some HTML elements around the page.